Dell PowerEdge R530 server hangs at startup
We have an R530 server reporting an error on iDRAC after a power outage.
Issue: When powered on, the server hangs at the "Initializing iDRAC" stage and does not receive an IP address.
The indicator on the iDRAC RJ45 port is not lit, and the front display shows "offline."
The fans run at full speed, and the console reports the following errors:

UEFI0315: Unable to process an iDRAC request to configure Secure Boot keys because of a communication error between BIOS and iDRAC.
SWC07000: iDRAC is not ready. The configuration values cannot be accessed.
UEFI0029: Unable to initialize iDRAC because of some critical issues.
The LifeCycle Manager is disabled. Attempting to make changes in the BIOS results in an error when saving.

What we've tried:
Replaced the iDRAC card with one from another working server, but the problem persisted.
Moved the NVRAM jumper, but it did not help.
Updated the BIOS to the latest version, but this did not resolve the issue.
Server specifications:
System BIOS Settings · System Information

System Model Name: PowerEdge R530
System BIOS Version: 2.9.1
System Management Engine Version: 3.1.3.38
System Service Tag: 1SY2NN2
System Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
System CPLD Version: 1.0.3
UEFI Compliance Version: 2.4

Hangs at startup screen
What other actions should I try?

What other actions should I try? - Contact Dell Support.

An R530 should be well past its service life.
